# Any way to make an improvement of neural network’s generalisation for feature month

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to develop a neural network for predicting the infection rate of a
coronavirus. I have a feature **monthOfYear**, and used one input node to represent it.
The node can take integer values from 1 to 12, indicating the month of the year. However, the
results showed that the neural network has poor generalization especially between December
of one year and January of the next year. Any suggestions to design a new representation of **monthOfYear**? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When representing a class (like a month) you should avoid integers and instead use a [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). This way the number 9 representing September does not get miss understood as being "less" than the month of December or 12.